# Classification of finite minimal non-solvable groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Is there any classification of finite minimal non-solvable groups? By minimal non-solvable group, I mean a non-solvable group all of whose proper subgroups are solvable.

Comment: For finite groups, the simple ones were classified by Thompson ([$N$-groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-group_(finite_group_theory))). A general such group $G$ would have a normal subgroup $N$ such that $G/N$ is a minimal simple group, and $N$ is solvable. I suspect there are too many examples to give a more precise classification.

Comment: Please make it clear whether you are asking about finite groups only (you have the tag "finite-groups") or about all groups.

Comment: @DerekHolt  Thank you, I corrected it.

Comment: Notice that Thompson's classification of $N$-groups includes  a classification of non-solvable finite groups with every proper section solvable (such groups being necessarily simple).